# Deserialize xml does not pick up element

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to deserialize some xml. Here it is:

```
<FooBars xmlns="http://foos">
  <Id1 xmlns="http://bars">2</Id1>
  <Id2 xmlns="http://bars">7</Id2>
  <Info xmlns="http://bars">
    <Data>
      <Field1>text1</Field1>
      <Field2>text2</Field2>
      <Field3>text3</Field3>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Field1>text5</Field1>
      <Field2>text6</Field2>
      <Field3>text7</Field3>
    </Data>
  </Info>
</FooBars>
```

I tried this:

```
var myData =  (FooBars)serializer.Deserialize(foobars.CreateReader());
...


[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FooBars", Namespace = "http://foos")]
public class FooBars
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id1", Namespace = "http://bars")]
    public string Id1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id2", Namespace = "http://bars")]
    public string Id2 { get; set; }  

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Info", Namespace = "http://bars")]
    public List<Data> Info { get; set; }

}

public class Data
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Field1")]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Field2")]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

But it looks like the Data class is not considered part of the xml, since it is not able to read it. I am getting all the other elements (ids) but not the things defined in Data.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Info missing a closing tag? Based on your indentation, is it meant to contain the Data elements?

Comment: Sorry, the missing tag is a copy error. I want the result to contain what is defined in the FooBars class. The Data part in the Info element is the one that is missing in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming missing `</Info>` tag is a typo, All you need is `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem`

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FooBars", Namespace = "http://foos")]
public class FooBars
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id1", Namespace = "http://bars")]
    public string Id1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id2", Namespace = "http://bars")]
    public string Id2 { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Info", Namespace = "http://bars"), XmlArrayItem("Data")] //<--
    public List<Data> Info { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML is missing a closing tag for `Info`.  Also, you need to defined the `Field3` property in the `Data` class and add the namespace 'http://bars' to it.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml is missing the info closing tag, meant to contain the Data elements then your classes should look something like:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FooBars", Namespace = "http://foos")]
public class FooBars
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id1", Namespace = "http://bars")]
    public string Id1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id2", Namespace = "http://bars")]
    public string Id2 { get; set; }  

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Info", Namespace = "http://bars")]
    public Info Information { get;set; }

}

public class Info {
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Data", Namespace = "")]
    public Info[] Info { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Field1")]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Field2")]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Notice how in your xml the info object basically contains all the data, not the FooBars like you designed the classes.

Comment: this makes sense. you wanted to do public Data[] Inf { get; set; } in the Info class I presume. Unfortunately this still does not work, as I get no Data objects back (they are null)

Answer (score 0):

via LinqPad - you can see the Field properties are null in the `myData.Info` property, and that is your problem, right? **UPDATED**:

```
void Main()
{
    string xmlString;
    string path = @"C:\Temp\exampleXmlSO.xml";

    using (StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        xmlString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FooBars));


    using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString))
    {
        var myData = (FooBars)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
        Console.WriteLine(myData);
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FooBars", Namespace = "http://foos")]
public class FooBars
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id1", Namespace = "http://bars")]
    public string Id1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id2", Namespace = "http://bars")]
    public string Id2 { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Info", Namespace = "http://bars"), XmlArrayItem("Data")] //<--
    public List<Data> Info { get; set; }

}


[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Field1")]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Field2")]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Hopefully someone else will get the answer before I get back` I already posted it before your answer. Tested with the xml in question.

Comment: yes, you did. i didn't realize. you get the credit, but updated mine for completeness. thanks.